# what kind of skills do i need to build a bittorrent client

Tags: networking, bittorrent

I have just finished my course in data structures. and now i was thinking of building a bit torrent client.

However when i googled the stuff i couldn't understand any of the terminologies such as sockets, ports etc.

I just need a general guidance of where to look. Books, tutorials anything else in general what kind of skills do i need to make a bit torrent client, what kind of language is suited best for the job or even what kind of courses should i look to in order to accomplish my goal.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: You need to learn sockets and threading.

Comment: Why build something that already exists! Dream up something new. napster, facebook etc are all created in college dorms..

Comment: well just to sharpen my skills i guess ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say one of the things you need to know is how computer networks work. This includes packet transmition, sockets, ports, threads, etc...

Computer networking is such a broad subject but I can leave here my personal sugestion of a book I loved to read and learn about computer networking (somewhat of an introduction to networking, but explains alot and even teaches you how to program in java using sockets).

> Computer Networking, a Top-Down Approach Featuring the Internet, James F. Kurose, Keith W. Ross, 2005, Addison-Wesley

It explains concepts like packet transmition, threading, sockets, ports and so much more. I recall it even has a section about torrents.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two parts: Architecture and Programming. First you need to architect the program. Architecture is the process of visualizing a large "system" as subsytems, define interfaces between them and then writing a "tune" to which they can dance.

For the above system, these are those "Subsystems" :

- Storage manager : Your torrent file is made of multiple chunks, which can be collected in any random order, assembled, verified and finally presented as a single file. Storage manager does this.
- Transport Manager : This system understands how to transport torrent chunks in and out. Given a packet it sends or given host it receives.
- Connection Manager: This system establishes connections to send and receive

etc etc.

Once you define the subsystems, then define what are the inputs and outputs. Then you develop each module.